# Make 50% of div not the browser width

Tags: html, css

I have `.left-navbar` and `.columns-wrapper` in which are two columns, `.left-column` and `.right-column`. The first column and second one has 50% of `.columns-wrapper` until I add `position: fixed` to `.right-column` and `.right-column` takes 50% of browser width not `.columns-wrapper`.

```css
.page-wrapper {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  background: red;
}

.page-wrapper .left-navbar {
  width: 88px;
  height: 100%;
  background: yellow;
}

.page-wrapper .columns-wrapper {
  width: calc(100% - 88px);
  height: 100%;
  background: orange;
  display: flex;
}

.page-wrapper .columns-wrapper .left-column {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
}

.page-wrapper .columns-wrapper .right-column {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="page-wrapper">
  <div class="left-navbar">

  </div>
  <div class="columns-wrapper">
    <div class="left-column"></div>
    <div class="right-column"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: please, can you edit your question adding a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example (minimal reproducible example)

Comment: `The fixed element is removed from the normal document flow, and no space is created for the element in the page layout. It is positioned relative to the initial containing block established by the viewport` from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)

Comment: so what I should change out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `columns-wrapper` position to `relative`, and `left-column` and `right-column` position to `absolute`.
Absolute position is related to the ancestors container which has the position value of `relative`.

`position: fixed` is related to the whole browser position, rather than its parent containers.

```
.page-wrapper .columns-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  ...
}

.page-wrapper .columns-wrapper .left-column {
  position: absolute;
  ...
}

.page-wrapper .columns-wrapper .right-column {
  position: absolute;
  ...
}
```

Comment: I want to add to the right column `position: fixed` to stay in the place when scrolling

Comment: `.right-column` takes 50% of div when is `position: absolute;` and it's a good. But when I want to add `position: fixed` it takes 50% of body not `.columns-wrapper`

Comment: Please raise it as another question.

Answer (score 0):

That behavior is completly normal as when you use a `fixed` position the element is removed from the normal content flow.

```css
#wrapper {
    width: 500px;
    background-color: cyan;
}

.w-1\/2 {
    width: 50%;
    background-color: red;
    height: 100px;
}

.fixed {
    position: fixed;
    width: 50%;
    height: 50px;
    background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="w-1/2">
  </div>
  
  <div class="fixed">
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see in example bellow even if I set it width to **50%** It doesn't take the 1/2 space of the `#wrapper` but for the body element.

```css
#wrapper {
    width: 500px;
    background-color: cyan;
}

.w-1\/2 {
    width: 50%;
    background-color: red;
    height: 100px;
}

.fixed {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    width: 50%;
    height: 50px;
    background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="w-1/2">
  </div>
  
  <div class="fixed">
  </div>
</div>
```